# Use highest value in column per level to calculate relative values in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I'm preparing data for a heatmap and I want to plot the changes relative to the highest value. I want to compare the patterns and not the absolute abundances per `id` and also limit the scale of the heatmap to 0 to 100 %.

This is my data:

```
head(kallisto_melt,14)

                id         protein_name variable     value relative_abundance
 1: BIJBGGEO_00001 hypothetical protein   tpm_A1 0.0000000                 NA
 2: BIJBGGEO_00001 hypothetical protein   tpm_A2 0.0000000                 NA
 3: BIJBGGEO_00001 hypothetical protein   tpm_A3 0.0000000                 NA
 4: BIJBGGEO_00001 hypothetical protein   tpm_A4 0.0000000                 NA
 5: BIJBGGEO_00001 hypothetical protein   tpm_A5 0.0000000                 NA
 6: BIJBGGEO_00001 hypothetical protein   tpm_A6 0.0000000                 NA
 7: BIJBGGEO_00001 hypothetical protein   tpm_A7 0.0000000                 NA
 8: BIJBGGEO_00002 hypothetical protein   tpm_A1 0.0000000                 NA
 9: BIJBGGEO_00002 hypothetical protein   tpm_A2 0.0000000                 NA
10: BIJBGGEO_00002 hypothetical protein   tpm_A3 0.0000000                 NA
11: BIJBGGEO_00002 hypothetical protein   tpm_A4 0.0703664                 NA
12: BIJBGGEO_00002 hypothetical protein   tpm_A5 0.0000000                 NA
13: BIJBGGEO_00002 hypothetical protein   tpm_A6 0.0000000                 NA
14: BIJBGGEO_00002 hypothetical protein   tpm_A7 0.0863996                 NA
```

I tried to add a column of relative values, which sets the highest `value` per `id` to 100 % and the other ones accordingly. I could imagine that all zeroes result in NA (the first 7 rows), but for the second `id` I expected something likes this:

```
                  id         protein_name variable     value relative_abundance
 1: BIJBGGEO_00001 hypothetical protein   tpm_A1 0.0000000                 NA
 2: BIJBGGEO_00001 hypothetical protein   tpm_A2 0.0000000                 NA
 3: BIJBGGEO_00001 hypothetical protein   tpm_A3 0.0000000                 NA
 4: BIJBGGEO_00001 hypothetical protein   tpm_A4 0.0000000                 NA
 5: BIJBGGEO_00001 hypothetical protein   tpm_A5 0.0000000                 NA
 6: BIJBGGEO_00001 hypothetical protein   tpm_A6 0.0000000                 NA
 7: BIJBGGEO_00001 hypothetical protein   tpm_A7 0.0000000                 NA
 8: BIJBGGEO_00002 hypothetical protein   tpm_A1 0.0000000                 0
 9: BIJBGGEO_00002 hypothetical protein   tpm_A2 0.0000000                 0
10: BIJBGGEO_00002 hypothetical protein   tpm_A3 0.0000000                 0
11: BIJBGGEO_00002 hypothetical protein   tpm_A4 0.0703664                 "somewhere about 81"
12: BIJBGGEO_00002 hypothetical protein   tpm_A5 0.0000000                 0
13: BIJBGGEO_00002 hypothetical protein   tpm_A6 0.0000000                 0
14: BIJBGGEO_00002 hypothetical protein   tpm_A7 0.0863996                 100
```

I adapted code I once asked for here [R how to calculate relative values based on a long format data.frame column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49282756/r-how-to-calculate-relative-values-based-on-a-long-format-data-frame-column)

and it looks like this:

```
 kallisto_melt[,relative_abundance := value/(value[max(value)]*100), by = .(id)]
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried `kallisto_melt[, relative_abundance := value / max(value)*100), by = id]` ?

Comment: if you remove the bracket behind `max(value)*100`, this works! Do you wanna turn this comment into an answer? It is closer to the question as it uses `data.table`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `data.table`, we can do

```
# setDT(kallisto_melt)
kallisto_melt[, relative_abundance := value / max(value) * 100, by = id]
kallisto_melt[is.na(relative_abundance), relative_abundance := 0]
kallisto_melt
#                id         protein_name variable     value #relative_abundance
# 1: BIJBGGEO_00001 hypothetical protein   tpm_A1 0.0000000            0.00000
# 2: BIJBGGEO_00001 hypothetical protein   tpm_A2 0.0000000            0.00000
# 3: BIJBGGEO_00001 hypothetical protein   tpm_A3 0.0000000            0.00000
# 4: BIJBGGEO_00001 hypothetical protein   tpm_A4 0.0000000            0.00000
# 5: BIJBGGEO_00001 hypothetical protein   tpm_A5 0.0000000            0.00000
# 6: BIJBGGEO_00001 hypothetical protein   tpm_A6 0.0000000            0.00000
# 7: BIJBGGEO_00001 hypothetical protein   tpm_A7 0.0000000            0.00000
# 8: BIJBGGEO_00002 hypothetical protein   tpm_A1 0.0000000            0.00000
# 9: BIJBGGEO_00002 hypothetical protein   tpm_A2 0.0000000            0.00000
#10: BIJBGGEO_00002 hypothetical protein   tpm_A3 0.0000000            0.00000
#11: BIJBGGEO_00002 hypothetical protein   tpm_A4 0.0703664           81.44297
#12: BIJBGGEO_00002 hypothetical protein   tpm_A5 0.0000000            0.00000
#13: BIJBGGEO_00002 hypothetical protein   tpm_A6 0.0000000            0.00000
#14: BIJBGGEO_00002 hypothetical protein   tpm_A7 0.0863996          100.00000
```

Answer (score 2):

use this code :- you will be able to find it.

```
library(dplyr)
df1 <- df %>%
  group_by(id,protein_name) %>%
  mutate(relative_abundance = value/max(value)*100)

df1[is.na(df1)] <- 0
```

Data :-

```
df<- structure(list(id = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("BIJBGGEO_00001", "BIJBGGEO_00002"
), class = "factor"), protein_name = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "hypothetical protein", class = "factor"), 
    variable = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 
    3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L), .Label = c("tpm_A1", "tpm_A2", "tpm_A3", 
    "tpm_A4", "tpm_A5", "tpm_A6", "tpm_A7"), class = "factor"), 
    value = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0703664, 0, 0, 
    0.0863996), relative_abundance = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-14L))
```

Comment: nice, this works! I would still go for markus solution (if he makes an answer out of it) as he uses data.table.